# How to loop elements from webpage that keeps refreshing the web elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I need to loop trough elements of a webpage and scrap data from each of the elements, but the webelements keep refreshing every 25 sec and my code does not finish iterating all elements in that amount of time, after that moment i get the `element is not attached to the page document` error:

```
driver.get("https://www.luckia.es/apuestas")
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame("sbtechBC")
eventos_de_hoy=driver.find_element_by_id("today_event_btn")
eventos_de_hoy.click()
time.sleep(7)
ligi = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leagueWindow ")
print(len(ligi))
for items in ligi:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", items)
    nume_liga= items.find_element_by_tag_name("h5")
    print(nume_liga.text)
```

I am fresh all out of ideas.

Comment: In other words, you want to wait until the page refreshes for the first time and then download new fresh data, right? Do you want to do it once or repeat periodically every 25 seconds?

Comment: @krokodilko sorry if i was not clear, i need to scrap some data from each of the elements, but until i manage to iterate all of the elements they refresh and i get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to avoid script brake on `StaleElementReferenceException`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.luckia.es/apuestas")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("sbtechBC"))
eventos_de_hoy = driver.find_element_by_id("today_event_btn")
eventos_de_hoy.click()

ligi_len = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leagueWindow "))))
print(ligi_len)
for index in range(ligi_len):
    try:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leagueWindow ")))[index]
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", item)
        nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5")
        print(nume_liga.text)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leagueWindow ")))[index]
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", item)
        nume_liga = item.find_element_by_tag_name("h5")
        print(nume_liga.text)
```

Comment: Great, this works, i did not even think to catch the exception as i thought that it will skip the element that raised the exception